# Google Search Appliance query request returns 502

Tags: java, httpresponse, google-search-appliance

In my Java project, i am using the [GSA Java API](http://gsa-japi.sourceforge.net/gsa-japi.html)  as an helper querying and getting results of a search. According to the API documentation, i believe i have done everything correct by the book. To test my first search operation, i have construct following URL

URL: `http://myHOST:myPORT/search?access=p&output=xml&client=&lr=tr&num=100&site=myXMLCollection`

and post it to the API hoping i was getting the results. But HTTP 502 error shows up.

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 502 for URL: http://myHOST:myPORT/search?access=p&output=xml&client=&lr=tr&num=100&site=myXMLCollection
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1626)
    at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1037)
    at net.sf.gsaapi.GSAClient.search(Unknown Source)
    at net.sf.gsaapi.GSAClient.getGSAResponse(Unknown Source)
    at net.sf.gsaapi.GSAClient.getGSAResponse(Unknown Source)
```

Am i missing something among the sent parameters?

Comment: `myHOST` - thats your host or google host? 502 is bad gateway. Can you open that url with browser?

Comment: I can open it. The full statement of the request url returns "unknown error occured" with blank page on browser.

Comment: I believe that you're missing the actual query... the `q=` parameter of the URL. If I recall correctly, the GSA will return an error if it's not present. You always have to search something, even if you want to retrieve all the indexed pages.

Comment: What do i need to type when i need all indexed pages?

Answer (score 1):

I could see couple of fields missing in your query.
Add the below parameters.

1. Query parameter i.e `q=your term`. If you are using java api, then set
   the query term using setQueryTerm(term) method.
2. Add the client, i.e Frontend. You can set using setFrontend(frontend) method
   in the Java API.
3. I persume your lr value is incorrect. It should be `lr=lang_tr`,if
   language is Turkish.

Regards,
Mohan

Comment: Is there any option that i could return all indexes from a collection?

Comment: you can use requiredfields search parameter. Remove the q parameter from the query and add requiredfields (&requiredfields=metadataName).The metadata which you are going to use in requiredfields must present in all pages.

Comment: If i am not wrong, GSA can return only upto 1000 results..Need to validate this..

Comment: Is it ok with GSA Java API? Do you recommend it?

Comment: If you want all the docs in a collection rather than running a search, you're better off using the admin API and hitting index diagnostics or exporting URLs.

Comment: You can use site: with the collection URL